# Get values of all selected checkboxes in multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of checkbox lists, and I want to alert the values of all selected checkboxes on click of a global button. Additionally, if there is a more "proper" way to do this rather than using inputs, or maybe using a form or series of forms, let me know.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="A" value="0">0</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="A" value="1">1</input>

<input type="checkbox" class="B" value="0">0</input>

<button onclick='return selectedvalues();'>GO!</button>
```

javascript:

```
function selected values(){
    //alert all selected values of checkboxes of classes A and B
}
```

Comment: @xFortyFourx it is tagged as such. However, if you have a nice no-jQuery solution, be sure to post anyways.

Comment: Yes I want JQUERY, thanks

Comment: And I'd like PONIES... Please, don't shout at us. It's not necessary; if you want to emphasise text use **bold** (`**bold**`) or *italic* (`*italic*`); or use the [tag:jquery] (`[tag:jquery]`) tag.

Comment: @JanDvorak ah thank you. My bad that I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function selectedValues(){
    //alert all selected values of checkboxes of classes A and B
    var $checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("class") + " " + $(this).val());
    });
}
```

This function will do the trick.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work, see the [jfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BPFTp/5/)

Comment: Your jsfiddle does not incorporate my code. I don't help people do homework specially. I forgot to make it only select checked items though, this has been fixed. Try again?

Comment: Sorry - I put the wrong link in. See the [jfiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/BPFTp/5/), though it still doesn't work.

Comment: $(this).val() instead of $(this).value()

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/BPFTp/5/ and you need to name the function without spaces

Comment: I am mystified by this. I updated it as you say, and it still doesn't work, see the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BPFTp/18/).

Comment: You didn't include jQuery.. In the left sidebar change "Underscore 1.4.3" to "jQuery 2.0.0".

Comment: What an embarassment on my part. Thank you - here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPFTp/23/).

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I had a few moments and thought I'd offer this interpretation:

```
function findChecked() {
    var group = document.getElementsByName(this.name),
        checked = [].map.call(group, function(a){
            a.nextElementSibling.style.color = a.checked ? 'limegreen' : '#000';
            if (a.checked) {
                return a;
            }
        }).filter(function(a){
            return 'undefined' !== typeof a;
        });
    return checked;
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'), function(a){
    a.addEventListener('change', findChecked);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BPFTp/22/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
function selected_values() {
 var messages = "";
 $("form input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){ 
 // Go through all checkboxes that are checked
  messages += $(this).val()  + "\n";
 });
 alert(messages);
}
```